# Array to string conversion Route::Group laravel

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-4, laravel-routing

i have the issues

Array to string conversion

vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Routing/Router.php line 976 (namespace)

```
protected function prependGroupUses($uses)
{
    $group = last($this->groupStack);

    return isset($group['namespace']) ? $group['namespace'].'\\'.$uses : $uses;
}
```

My route.php

```
Route::group(array('domain' => 'subdomain.abc.com','prefix' => 'admin','namespace' => 'Admin\Controllers'), function() {
# User Management
Route::get('users/{id}/edit', array('as'=>'users.edit','uses' => 'UsersController@getEdit'));
Route::post('users/{id}/edit', array('as'=>'users.edit','uses' => 'UsersController@postEdit'));
#Route::get('users/{id}/delete', array('as'=>'users.delete')'UsersController@getDelete');
Route::post('users/{id}/delete', array('as'=>'users.delete','uses' => 'UsersController@postDelete'));
Route::controller('users', array('as'=>'users','uses' => 'UsersController'));

# Group Management
Route::get('groups/{id}/edit', array('as'=>'groups.edit','uses' => 'GroupsController@getEdit'));
Route::post('groups/{id}/edit', array('as'=>'groups.edit','uses' => 'GroupsController@postEdit'));
Route::post('groups/{id}/delete', array('as'=>'groups.delete','uses' => 'GroupsController@postDelete'));
Route::controller('groups', array('as'=>'groups','uses' => 'GroupsController'));
});
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`Route::controller` takes 3 arguments.

```
public function controller($uri, $controller, $names = array())
```

So you are currently passing an array to the second argument instead of a string.

**Ref**

[API Routing Router](http://laravel.com/api/4.2/Illuminate/Routing/Router.html)